# How to conditional set up a Makefile variable by testing if a file exists

Tags: makefile

For example:
I want:

if file1 exists:

```
CLEAN_SRC = *.h file3
```

else

```
CLEAN_SRC =
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If `file1` does not exist then `$(wildcard file1)` will evaluate to an empty string.

```
ifeq ($(wildcard file1),) 
    CLEAN_SRC =
else 
    CLEAN_SRC = *.h file3
endif
```

Comment: Be careful about indentation and TAB/space characters. E.g. CLEAN_SRC needed to be separated by a TAB char otherwise it would throw `no separator` error.

Comment: @ArunM: I don't think that's true about the TAB/space characters.  Only the *rule definitions* require Tab indentation.  Other parts of the makefile can be indented by spaces, or not at all -- make doesn't care there.

Comment: $(realpath file1) would be an alternative to $(wildcard file1) in this context, since it would also evaluate to an empty string if the file is missing.

Comment: However, I've been told that $(wildcard file1) is favored over $(realpath file1) because it doesn't print a message that could mistakenly be thought to indicate an error.

Comment: I'd write the positive case first with `ifneq ($(wildcard file1),)` and then the "file does not exist" would be the `else` case.