# make: Error in ifneq: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: makefile

I would like to create a makefile for LaTeX documents (in this minimal
example). When there is no file "makeindexstyle.ist", it should be created (by
running make makeindexstyle.ist) and used for formatting the index. The rule for
`%.pdf` reflects this. However, it is not working yet, I receive the error

```
ifneq (, ) {
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
make: *** [master.pdf] Error 2
```

What's wrong?

```
Parts from Makefile:

MASTER = master
TEX = slave

TEXI = texi2dvi -p

all: $(MASTER:=.pdf)

%.pdf: %.tex $(TEX:=.tex)
    ifneq ($(wildcard makeindexstyle.ist), ) { # if makeindexstyle.ist exists, compile and build index
        $(TEXI) $<
        make makeindexstyle.ist
        makeindex -c -s makeindexstyle.ist $(MASTER:=.idx)
    }
    endif
    $(TEXI) $<

makeindexstyle.ist:
    @(echo "...") > makeindexstyle.ist
```

UPDATE:
I tried to make it as simple as possible to see where the error comes from. Among other things (like quoting), I tried this:

```
%.pdf: %.tex $(TEX:=.tex)
    exist := $(wildcard "absolute-path-to-makeindexstyle.ist")
    ifneq ($strip $(exist)),)
             echo "foo"
    endif
    $(TEXI) $<
```

but the result is

```
exists := 
make: exists: Command not found
make: *** [book.pdf] Error 127
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meanwhile, I could solve it on the shell side:

```
IDX = "makeindexstyle.ist"
%.pdf: %.tex $(TEX:=.tex)
    @if test -f $(IDX); then \
        echo "foo"; \
    fi
    $(TEXI) $<
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this for anyone who experiences this error as I did. [This site](https://www.kianmeng.org/2020/11/resolving-syntax-error-word-unexpected.html) is what I stumbled upon after this post and it explains it is a problem with indentation.

This code causes the error

```
target : dependencies
    ifneq (condition)
        body1
    else
        body2
    endif
```

But this code functions as expected

```
target : dependecies
ifneq (condition)
    body1
else
    body2
endif
```

Makefiles are wierd.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a duplicate of [How do I check if file exists in Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553352/check-if-a-file-exists) or [How to conditional set up a Makefile variable by testing if a file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077676/how-to-conditional-set-up-a-makefile-variable-by-testing-if-a-file-exists).

Try

```
ifneq ($(wildcard makeindexstyle.ist),)
```

without the space. Alternatively, throw `""` around the arguments?

Comment: Thanks, Quuxplusone. I knew the two links (and many others). Still, this does not solve the problem. I also tried the quoting (although I think it's not necessary), as described here: http://www.humbug.in/2012/makefile-check-if-a-file-exists-using-wildcard-function/. Still no luck. I'll post an update soon which also failed, maybe that reveals my wrong way of thinking here.