# Conditional change of Makefile variable (Application to unit testing of static function)

Tags: unit-testing, makefile

Originally I wanted to automatically include helpers to unit-test static functions by using *--include* gcc keyword like described in the link below:

[How to test a static function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/593414/3972710)

The idea is to automatically include a foo.cu ( **c**/c++ for **u**nit ) making calls to static functions defined in foo.cc

I read several answers like

[How to conditional set up a Makefile variable by testing if a file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1077676/3972710)

[Define make variable at rule execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1909188/3972710)

[How do I check if file exists in Makefile so I can delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5553352/3972710)

but syntax like the one below was not successful (even with characters alignment to the target...)

```makefile
#did not work
ifneq ($(wildcard $(UT_FILE_LOC)),)
    $(eval LOC_CPPFLAGS := $(CPPFLAGS) --include $(UT_FILE_LOC))
else
    $(eval LOC_CPPFLAGS := $(CPPFLAGS) )
endif
```

and I ended-up with syntax

```makefile
$(eval LOC_CPPFLAGS := $(shell [[ -e $(UT_FILE_LOC) ]] && echo $(CPPFLAGS) --include $(UT_FILE_LOC) || echo $(CPPFLAGS) ))
```

**Question:**
Is this a correct way to modify/orientate the value of a makefile variable ?

=========================================================

MCVE for the makefile itself

```makefile
SRCDIR   = src
SRCFILES = $(wildcard src/*.cc)
OBJDIR   = obj
DEPDIR   = dep
OBJFILES = $(patsubst %.cc,$(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SRCFILES))
DEPFILES = $(patsubst %.cc,$(DEPDIR)/%.d, $(SRCFILES))

#just some flags for this MCVE
CPPFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -Weffc++

main: $(OBJFILES)
    g++ -o $@ $^ 

# Include dependencies ( change in foo.cu are seen )
-include $(DEPFILES)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cc
    @echo '> Compiling source file: $<'
    @install -d $(OBJDIR)/$(dir $<)
    @install -d $(DEPDIR)/$(dir $<)
    $(eval UT_FILE_LOC  :=  $(patsubst %.cc,%.cu,$<))
    $(eval LOC_CPPFLAGS := $(shell [[ -e $(UT_FILE_LOC) ]] && echo $(CPPFLAGS) --include $(UT_FILE_LOC) || echo $(CPPFLAGS) ))

    g++ -c $(LOC_CPPFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF"$(DEPDIR)/$*.d" -o $@ $<

clean:
    $(RM) -r $(OBJDIR)/*
    $(RM) -r $(DEPDIR)/*
```

and with basic C++ files (foo.cc, foo.cu and main)

```c
#include <iostream>
static void foo() {
   std::cout << "foo" << "\n" << std::flush;
}

void bar() {  foo(); } //avoid unused foo() warning for this MCVE
```

```c
static void foo();

void ut_foo() {
    return foo();
}
```

```c
void ut_foo();

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ut_foo();
    return 0;
}
```

---

*--include src/foo.cu* is visible for foo.cc compilation and not for the other files (well, here just the main...).

```
> Compiling source file: src/foo.cc
g++ -c -std=c++11 -Wall -Weffc++ --include src/foo.cu -MMD -MP -MF"dep/src/foo.d" -o obj/src/foo.o src/foo.cc
> Compiling source file: src/main_unit.cc
g++ -c -std=c++11 -Wall -Weffc++ -MMD -MP -MF"dep/src/main_unit.d" -o obj/src/main_unit.o src/main_unit.cc
g++ -o main obj/src/foo.o obj/src/main_unit.o 

./main 
foo
```

Interestingly foo.cu appears in foo.o dependency and a change to foo.cu restart the compilation of foo.c (so no extra work to be done for this point)

> obj/src/foo.o: src/foo.cc src/foo.cu
>
> src/foo.cu:

=========================================================

Comment: Solution proposed by MadScientist : remove $( eval ... ) lines and put
g++ -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(if $(wildcard $*.cu),--include $*.cu) -MMD -MP -MF"$(DEPDIR)/$*.d" -o $@ $<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it's (virtually) *never* correct to use `$(eval ...)` inside of a rule.  Whenever you see any "tutorial" or "advice" blog that shows using `eval` (or `$(shell ...)`) inside a recipe, unless it's some extraordinarily bizarre situation, it's probably best to skip it.

Firstly, `CPPFLAGS` is not the right variable; the "CPP" here stands for "C preprocessor" not "C++".  This variable is traditionally expected to contain preprocessor flags like `-I`, `-D`, etc.  The standard variable for C++-specific options is `CXXFLAGS`.

Secondly, this solution seems very over-complex to me.  Wouldn't this work:

```
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -Weffc++ $(if $(wildcard $*.cu),--include $*.cu)
```

??

Comment: It makes me very sad to see the number of upvotes for the answer you link to recommending `eval`.  The right answer to that question is https://stackoverflow.com/a/29085760/939557 not the accepted answer.

Comment: Your proposed solution works perfectly. Thank you for recalling the CXXFLAGS correct naming. I will have a look to the right answer you pointed